# Why is Corki underplayed?

Tags: league-of-legends

- His passive applies 10% of his ad as true damage
- Great escape utility/team positioning with his w
- Great wave clear potential
- Extremely long range poke with short cooldown

Why is it that he isn't a frequently played champion in bot. I understand that most people say that his early game is a pain, but from my experience his auto attacks accompanied by his passive will destroy 1 bar of health from the opponent each time he attacks them.

Is there some reason? Is he hard to master? Extremely boring? (which I totally disagree) or because his figure doesn't look appealing?

Comment: The answer to this question feels subjective or at least transient. I know that, in late 2012, he was one of the "[flavors of the month](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=817614)" (alongside Graves and Ezreal) and was played quite often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience the downside of corki is that he is hard to master (like you mentioned).
He also has a relatively short range auto attack which makes it even harder. His Ult is one of the toughest skillshots in the game (to hit if no minions are around) and in order to utilize his E which is a great armor shred you need to really get in there which can be tricky for an ad carry. Plus there are other carries out there with even better lane harass (than his passive). Like draven for example. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: And he hasn't any steroids